# How to create a formulated table in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr

This is my reproducible example :

```
#http://gekkoquant.com/2012/05/26/neural-networks-with-r-simple-example/

library("neuralnet")
require(ggplot2)

traininginput <-  as.data.frame(runif(50, min=0, max=100))
trainingoutput <- sqrt(traininginput)
trainingdata <- cbind(traininginput,trainingoutput)
colnames(trainingdata) <- c("Input","Output")

Hidden_Layer_1 <- 1       # value is randomly assigned 
Hidden_Layer_2 <- 1       # value is randomly assigned
Threshold_Level <- 0.1    # value is randomly assigned

net.sqrt <- neuralnet(Output~Input,trainingdata, hidden=c(Hidden_Layer_1, Hidden_Layer_2), threshold = Threshold_Level)

#Test the neural network on some test data
testdata <- as.data.frame((1:13)^2)              #Generate some squared numbers
net.results <- predict(net.sqrt, testdata)       #Run them through the neural network

cleanoutput <- cbind(testdata,sqrt(testdata),
                     as.data.frame(net.results))

colnames(cleanoutput) <- c("Input","ExpectedOutput","NeuralNetOutput")

ggplot(data = cleanoutput, aes(x= ExpectedOutput, y= NeuralNetOutput)) + geom_point() +
  geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1
              , color="brown", size=0.5)

rmse <- sqrt(sum((sqrt(testdata)- net.results)^2)/length(net.results))

print(rmse)
```

At here, when my `Hidden_Layer_1` is `1`, `Hidden_Layer_2` is `2`, and the `Threshold_Level` is `0.1`, my `rmse` generated is `0.6717354`.

Let's say we try for the other example,

when my `Hidden_Layer_1` is `2`, `Hidden_Layer_2` is `3`, and the `Threshold_Level` is `0.2`, my `rmse` generated is `0.8355925`.

How can I create a table  that will automatically calculate the value of `rmse` when user assign value to the `Hidden_Layer_1`, `Hidden_Layer_2`, and `Threshold_Level`. ( I know how to do it in Excel but not in `r` haha )

The desired table should be looked like this :

[image]

I wish that I have `Trial(s)`, `Hidden_Layer_1`, `Hidden_Layer_2`, `Threshold_Level`, and `rmse` in my column, and the number of rows can be generated infinitely by entering some `actionButton` (if possible), means user can keep on trying until they got the `rmse` they desired.

How can I do that? Can anyone help me? I will definitely learn from this lesson as I am quite new to `r`.
Thank you very much for anyone who willing to give a helping hand to me.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to create the table of values that can be displayed with the data frame viewer.

```
# initialize an object where we can store the parameters as a data frame
data <- NULL

# function to receive a row of parameters and add them to the
# df argument
addModelElements <- function(df,trial,layer1,layer2,threshold,rmse){
     newRow <- data.frame(trial = trial,
                          Hidden_Layer_1 = layer1,
                          Hidden_Layer_2 = layer2,
                          Threshold = threshold,
                          RMSE = rmse)
     rbind(df,newRow)
}

# once a model has been run, call addModelElements() with the 
# model parameters 
data <- addModelElements(data,1,1,2,0.1,0.671735)
data <- addModelElements(data,2,2,3,0.2,0.835593)
```

...and the output:

```
View(data)
```

[image]

Note that if you're going to create scores or hundreds of rows of parameters & RMSE results before displaying any of them to the end user, the code should be altered to improve the efficiency of `rbind()`. In this scenario, we build a list of sets of parameters, convert them into data frames, and use `do.call()` to execute `rbind()` only once.

```
# version that improves efficiency of `rbind()
addModelElements <- function(trial,layer1,layer2,threshold,rmse){
     # return row as data frame
     data.frame(trial = trial,
                Hidden_Layer_1 = layer1,
                Hidden_Layer_2 = layer2,
                Threshold = threshold,
                RMSE = rmse)
}

# generate list of data frames and rbind() once

inputParms <- list(c(1,1,2,0.1,0.671735),
                   c(1,1,2,0.3,0.681935),
                   c(2,2,3,0.2,0.835593))

parmList <- lapply(inputParms,function(x){
     addModelElements(x[1],x[2],x[3],x[4],x[5])
})
# bind to single data frame
data <- do.call(rbind,parmList)
View(data)
```

...and the output:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Len Greski , thanks for the help! But I have 1 question don't understand. seems like the value of RMSE is we inserted manually, but in my program above, the `rmse` is calculated by the formula `sqrt(sum((sqrt(testdata)- net.results)^2)/length(net.results))`. How can I apply this formula into the table? Because after that I need to apply it into `shiny` for user interface :D

Comment: @Gambit - Since your post wasn't a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) I couldn't exactly replicate your situation. However, once `rmse` is calculated in your code, you can use it as the `rmse` argument in `addModelElements()`.